# Cannot redeclare class error with CodeCoverage and Composer

Tags: phpunit, code-coverage, autoload, composer-php

I'm getting an error with PHPUnit Code_Coverage when using Composer's autoload.php as the bootstrap file. I've created my own boostrap.php file and simply include each file individually and everything works fine. Have I stumbled onto a Composer bug, or am I making an error somewhere?

// Edit: I'm using the newest (to-date) versions of everything: PHPUnit 3.7.12, Code_Coverage 1.2.7, Composer b51a4a7

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class C3\CDN\EdgeCast in /Users/kperrine/Projects/edgecast-custom-reports/src/C3/CDN/EdgeCast.php on line 11

Call Stack:
    0.0017     641760   1. {main}() /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/bin/phpunit:0
    0.2232    1111312   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/bin/phpunit:46
    0.2232    1112040   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/lib/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:129
    0.3027    4636952   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/lib/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:176
   21.5764    6604032   5. PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_HTML->process() /Users/kperrine/Projects/edgecast-custom-reports/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:384
   21.5764    6604240   6. PHP_CodeCoverage->getReport() /Users/kperrine/Projects/edgecast-custom-reports/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/PHP/CodeCoverage/Report/HTML.php:120
   21.5768    6663512   7. PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_Factory->create() /Users/kperrine/Projects/edgecast-custom-reports/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/PHP/CodeCoverage.php:158
   21.5769    6663512   8. PHP_CodeCoverage->getData() /Users/kperrine/Projects/edgecast-custom-reports/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/PHP/CodeCoverage/Report/Factory.php:64
   21.5769    6663512   9. PHP_CodeCoverage->addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist() /Users/kperrine/Projects/edgecast-custom-reports/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/PHP/CodeCoverage.php:190
   21.5769    6664408  10. PHP_CodeCoverage->processUncoveredFileFromWhitelist() /Users/kperrine/Projects/edgecast-custom-reports/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/PHP/CodeCoverage.php:535
   21.5778    6757272  11. include_once('/Users/kperrine/Projects/edgecast-custom-reports/src/C3/CDN/EdgeCast.php') /Users/kperrine/Projects/edgecast-custom-reports/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/PHP/CodeCoverage.php:558
```

My phpunit.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="C3 EdgeCast Tests">
            <directory>./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="log/report" charset="UTF-8"
            highlight="false" lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with my use of namespaces in the project. My project namespace is `C3\CDN\EdgeCast` (note the capital 'C' in EdgeCast), but when I used the namespace in the test file I accidentally typed `use C3\CDN\Edgecast;` (note the lower case 'c' in Edgecast). The difference in the name caused either CodeCoverage or Composer (I don't know which exactly) to think the class hadn't been included and thus tried to include it again.

Moral of the story: *Always double check your class and namespace names.*

Comment: The same thing happened to me, because I had the wrong case for a letter in one of my class names.

Answer (score 0):

Is phpunit installed with composer in the project as well? If so you probably want to remove the bootstrap because it would already be included by calling phpunit.

I am not sure what you mean by "simply include each file individually". You mean if you don't use the autoloader but include stuff manually it works? That would be quite strange. Using the autoloader generally works fine.

If all else fails, can you try to create a simple reproduce case with a composer.json and a couple classes that make it fail when phpunit is ran?

Comment: No, PHPUnit is installed separately on the machine. By "simply including each file" I mean that I created a bootstrap.php file that contains the following and code-coverage works just fine.

    require "path/to/file1.php";
    require "path/to/file2.php";
    require "path/to/fileN.php";

Answer (score 0):

The include is made during the processing step for `processUncoveredFileFromWhitelist="true"` in which PHPUnit includes all files in `src` that don't have coverage information.

My guess would be that something in there is including something. It also might be an issue with the class that has already been autoloaded (iirc composer uses just `require` and not `require_once` (rightfully though!) being included again.

In all cases so far where this error pops up it was because if include/require statements in the code. If that is not the case, and it's ofc possible, then it's an issue somewhere in phpunit but a quite strange one.

What always works is setting `processUncoveredFileFromWhitelist="false"` which will still list all files but not include them. The coverage information for uncovered files will differ a little but much. (The amount of lines executable is then smartly guessed instead of taken from xdebug)

Comment: Yeah, I switched processUncovered to false, but then it doesn't get the code coverage right **at all**, so that isn't an option. The extra require in src directory was my first thought, but I've been through it completely and there are no requires in that code anywhere.

Comment: Interesting. It should guess quite correctly (and that only applies for uncovered files anyways). If you have samples where it's off by a lot I'd be interested in a bug report if you have the time :)

Comment: I just re-checked it, and yes, it was off a lot in this situation, because of the incorrect namespace (see my own answer to this question). If I set processUncovered to be false, and leave the namespace incorrect, I get a measly 1.5% of lines covered. However, once the namespace is corrected, and I still leave uncovered to false, the lines covered jumps to 53.44%. This is the same percentage returned when processUncovered is set to true, because all files are uncovered by the tests.